# select jquery плагин с поддерржкой аттрибута required

Tags: jquery, select, плагин

Не удается найти замену стандартному select'у, чтобы соответствовал требованиям:

1. Поддерживал атрибут required - т.е. в случае, если не выбран элемент выпадающего списка, при попытке отправки формы браузер подсвечивал элемент красным и показывал подсказку "Пожалуйста, заполните это поле"
2. Понимал ширину в процентах
3. Поддавался стилизации (цвет рамки, текста, стилизация индикатора стрелки и т.п.)
4. Не создавал проблем с позиционированием inline-block элементов после себя (как это происходит в случае с selectize.js).

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: а обычный почему не подходит?

Comment: нужна стилизация стрелки "вниз"

Comment: Это делается и в обычном select

Comment: можно пример - как? нужно чтобы выглядел как jQuery Nice Select

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38870462/5376639

Comment: [CodePen select arrow](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=select+arrow&limit=all&type=type-pens)

Comment: Спасибо, но данные решения, к сожалению, не подходят в качестве решения моей проблемы, поскольку не поддерживают ширину в процентах - там везде ширина задается в пикселях :(

Comment: Удалось решить задачу с помощью  вендорных перфиксов appearance:

Comment: .select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.select:after {
  content: "▼";
  padding: 0 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 4px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
select {
  padding-right: 25px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
  }